# instantiating two unrelated subclasses using factory design pattern?

Tags: c#

As per my understanding, We can use factory if we have same method implemented by subclasses, something like this

```
interface IAnimal
{
    void Eat();
}
class Bird : IAnimal
{
    public void Eat()
    {
        // bird eats grain
    }
}

class Tiger : IAnimal
{
    public void Eat()
    {
        // Tiger eats meat
    }
}
```

our factory

```
class AnimalFactory
{
    public IAnimal GetInstance(int type)
    {
        // dependind on type we can return
        // animal
    }
}
```

but what if we have another different method in the subclasses like Fly() in Bird class and Walk() in Tiger class?

```
class Bird : IAnimal
{
    public void Eat()
    {
        // bird eats grain
    }
    public void Fly()
    {

    }
}

class Tiger : IAnimal
{
    public void Eat()
    {
        // Tiger eats meat
    }
    public void Walk()
    {
 
    }
}
```

What is the best way to implement? I think, since subclasses do not implement completely one interface, so we should not use a factory design pattern? Of course we can still use and client can use `Fly()` and `Walk()` method by casting it back to the respective classes.

But my question is, is this still a valid use case for implementing factory design pattern?

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: thing is: when you request an `iAnimal`-object from your factory, you _should not care_ whether it can fly or not. so the question is moot.

Comment: Why not use `Move()` for both classes? `Tiger` would implement `Move()` by walking. `Bird` would implement `Move()` by flying. The whole idea behind interfaces is that you don't need to know how the class implements the functionality, just that it does.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a factory and the calling code cares whether the returned animal can fly or walk, then the factory needs to return a more-derived type.

```
interface IAnimal { void Eat(); }
interface IFlyingAnimal : IAnimal { void Fly(); }
interface IWalkingAnimal : IAnimal { void Walk(); }

class Tiger : IWalkingAnimal
{
    public void Eat() { }
    public void Walk() { }
}

class Bird : IFlyingAnimal
{
    public void Eat() { }
    public void Fly() { }
}

// The factory lets the caller choose which type of animal it wants:

class AnimalFactory
{
    public IFlyingAnimal GetFlyingAnimal() { return new Bird(); }
    public IWalkingAnimal GetWalkingAnimal() { return new Tiger(); }
}

// or, you can use separate factories:

class FlyingAnimalFactory
{
    public IFlyingAnimal Get() { return new Bird(); }
}

class WalkingAnimalFactory
{
    public IWalkingAnimal Get() { return new Tiger(); }
}
```

This may or may not be the right solution, depending on the code you are writing. You should choose a pattern that fits your needs.

Your original factory accepts an `int type` parameter, which makes me think the calling code probably knows it needs a Tiger or a Bird. So other solutions might be to not use a factory, or have the factory return a Tiger specifically:

```
public void AnimalFactory
{
    public Tiger GetTiger() { return new Tiger(); }
    public Bird GetBird() { return new Bird(); }
}
```